# Not getting the shadow on the winner tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a rock paper Scissors game in html css and js and the game is working fine but there is a slight problem i added a feature that whichever side wins either the computer or the user there should be a shadow behind the winner tab and that too is working but the problem is that it is totally random even when i put that in a condition of when to toggle and it gives the shadow to wrong tab and sometimes to both tabs here is the code:
HTML AND JS:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow&family=Barlow+Condensed&family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Rock Paper Scisccor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scoreboard">
        <div class="name">
            <ul>
                <li id="rock"><strong> ROCK </strong> </li>
                <li id="Paper"><strong> PAPER </strong> </li>
                <li id="Scissors"><strong> SCISSORS </strong> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="score">
            <div id="score_name"><strong>SCORE</strong></div>
            <div id="score_value"><strong>0</strong></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-game">
        <div id="inside_main">
            <div class="items" id="rock_1" onclick="rock_2()">
                <button class="inside_color">

                    <img src="rock-paper-scissors-master\rock-paper-scissors-master\images\1.svg" alt="">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="items" id="paper_1" onclick="paper_2()">
                <button class="inside_color">

                    <img src="rock-paper-scissors-master\rock-paper-scissors-master\images\2.svg" alt="">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="items" id="scissors_1" onclick="scissors_2()">
                <button class="inside_color">
                    <img src="rock-paper-scissors-master\rock-paper-scissors-master\images\3.svg" alt="">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="results">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="left_side">YOU PICKED</div>
            <div id="left_content">
                <div class="items_1" id="user" >
                    <div class="inside_color" >
                        <img id="user_img" src="rock-paper-scissors-master\rock-paper-scissors-master\images\3.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="play-again">
            <div class="result" id="result_value"> YOU LOSE</div>
            <button type="button" class="button-play" onclick="btn()">PLAY AGAIN</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content_1">
            <div id="right_side">HOUSE PICKED</div>
            <div id="right_content">
                <div class="items_1" id="computer" >
                    <div class="inside_color">
                        <img id="computer_img" src="rock-paper-scissors-master\rock-paper-scissors-master\images\3.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="pics">
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        let score = 0
        
        function condition(user_choice){

            document.getElementById('inside_main').style.display='none'
            document.getElementById('results').style.display='grid'
            
            let res = 0
            let computer_choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            if(user_choice==1 && computer_choice==3){
                console.log('you win')
                score = score+1
                res = 1
                }
                
            else if(user_choice==2 && computer_choice==1){
                console.log('you win')
                score = score+1
                res = 1
            }
            else if(user_choice==3 && computer_choice==2){
                console.log('you win')
                score = score+1
                res = 1
                
            }
            else if(user_choice==computer_choice){
                console.log('draw')
                score = score
                res = -1
            }
            else{
                console.log('you lose')
                score = score-1
                res = 0
            }
            
            document.getElementById('user_img').src='rock-paper-scissors-master/rock-paper-scissors-master/images/'+user_choice+'.svg'
            document.getElementById('computer_img').src='rock-paper-scissors-master/rock-paper-scissors-master/images/'+computer_choice+'.svg'
            document.getElementById('score_value').innerHTML=score
            if (res==0){
                document.getElementById('result_value').innerHTML='YOU LOSE'
                document.getElementById('computer').classList.toggle("big_hover")
                console.log(res)
                
            }
            else if(res == -1){
                document.getElementById('result_value').innerHTML='DRAW'
                console.log(res)
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('result_value').innerHTML='YOU WON'
                document.getElementById('user').classList.toggle("big_hover")
                console.log(res)
            }
            // let res = 0
            
        }
    
        function rock_2(){
            let user_choice = 1
            
            condition(user_choice)
        }
        function paper_2(){
            let user_choice = 2
            
            condition(user_choice)
        }

        function scissors_2(){
            let user_choice = 3
            
            condition(user_choice)
        }

        function btn(){
            document.getElementById('inside_main').style.display='flex'
            document.getElementById('results').style.display='none'
            // let res = 0
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:-

```
body{
    margin: 2px 2px;
    /* font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif; */
/* font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif; */
    font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
    background-image: radial-gradient( hsl(214, 47%, 23%) , hsl(237, 49%, 15%));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}


.scoreboard{
    width: 40%;
    height: 10rem;
    display: flex;
    gap: 30%;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
.name{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    /* border: 2px solid white; */
    margin: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    align-self: center;
}
.name ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px ;
    /* border: 2px solid yellow; */
}
.score{
    display: flex;
    /* align-self: center; */
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* padding: 7%;    */
    width: 40%;
    /* height: 40vh; */
    margin: 3%;
}
#score_name{
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    padding: 5px;
    color: hsl(229, 64%, 46%);
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}
#score_value{
    color: hsl(229, 25%, 31%);
    font-size: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
}
.main-game{
    margin-top: 4%;
}
/* .inside_main ::after{
    content: '';
    background: url("rock-paper-scissors-master/rock-paper-scissors-master/images/bg-triangle.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
} */
#inside_main{
    display: flex;
    /* border: 2px solid whitesmoke; */
    width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
    height: 60vh;
}
.items{
    height: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: grid;
    /* background-color: white; */
}
.items:hover::before{
    content: '';
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    height: 285px;
    width: 285px;
    opacity: 10%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.inside_color img{
    display: grid;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
}
.inside_color{
    display: grid;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    height: 182px;
    width: 182px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#rock_1{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(349, 71%, 52%) , hsl(349, 70%, 56%));
}
#paper_1{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(230, 89%, 62%) , hsl(230, 89%, 65%));
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    /* left: 25%; */
}
#scissors_1{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(39, 89%, 49%) , hsl(40, 84%, 53%));

}
#results{
    display: none;
    /* border: 2px solid white; */
    width: 50%;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat (2,auto );
    row-gap: 20%;
    justify-content: center;
    /* padding: 40px; */
}
.content_1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat (2,auto );
    row-gap: 20%;
    justify-content: center;
    /* padding: 40px; */
}
.play-again{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 10%;
    justify-content: center;

}
#left_side{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#right_side{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#scissors_1{
    border: 2px solid white;
}
.result{
    /* border: 2px solid white; */
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
}
.button-play{
    /* border: 2px solid white; */
    border-radius: 6%;
    width: 25vh;
    height: 80%;
}
#user{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(39, 89%, 49%) , hsl(40, 84%, 53%));

}
#computer{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(349, 71%, 52%) , hsl(349, 70%, 56%));
}

.items_1{
    height: 225px;
    width: 225px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: grid;
    /* background-color: white; */
}

.big_hover::before{
    content: '';
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    height: 385px;
    width: 385px;
    opacity: 10%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the change you need to have in your `if-else` structure:

```js
if (res==0){
        document.getElementById('result_value').innerHTML='YOU LOSE';
        document.getElementById('user').classList.remove("big_hover")
        document.getElementById('computer').classList.add("big_hover")
        console.log(res)
        
    }
    else if(res == -1){
        document.getElementById('result_value').innerHTML='DRAW'
        document.getElementById('user').classList.remove("big_hover")
        document.getElementById('computer').classList.remove("big_hover")
        console.log(res)
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('result_value').innerHTML='YOU WON'
        document.getElementById('user').classList.add("big_hover")
        document.getElementById('computer').classList.remove("big_hover")
        console.log(res)
    }
```

With the above code you can insure that the winner side gets shadow and other side looses shadow and on draw both side loose shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Donot use toggle , instead before result remove all shadow class from all tabs then add shadow class where win tab is.